# Split information into columns using ItemControls with XAML

Tags: windows-10, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app I'm showing a value for each hour of the day. I'm new to XAML so my first attempt was to build 4 columns with 6 textblocks each to show the entire info.

[image: Screenshot]

I was looking for a better way to do this using a repeater like ItemsControl but my problem is:

How can I split the info into 4 columns (6 hours per column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was doing it all wrong.

I have to use the ItemsWrapGrid to split my information into a fixed number of rows like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="thisGrid">
    <GridView x:Name="thisGridView">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid
                        x:Name="thisItemsWrapGrid"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        MaximumRowsOrColumns="6"
                    />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="00:00 0,084"/>
        <TextBlock Text="01:00 0,077"/>
        <TextBlock Text="02:00 0,071"/>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```